# adding values put in by users

Tags: android, getvalue

i am trying to write some sort of code, which adds two numbers the user puts in, this is my code:

```
l.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                int i= Integer.parseInt(l.input1.getText().toString());
                int j= Integer.parseInt(l.input2.getText().toString());
                int sum = i+j;
                    l.result.setText(sum);
                }
            });
```

for some reason the emulator just collapse, i am new to this all, and am  really greatfull for any help. THANK YOU.

Comment: can you please add the error displayed in logcat.?

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` of TextView either accepts a String value as parameter to display or a integer value which is a `string resource id` that you have described in res/values/strings.xml

The integer value you passing is a real value and you have make the TextView to understand it as real value and not a String resource reference. So convert the integer to String and then set the value inside text view.

Solution:

```
l.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i= Integer.parseInt(l.input1.getText().toString());
                int j= Integer.parseInt(l.input2.getText().toString());
                int sum = i+j;
                l.result.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        });
```